# Connect RabbitMQ container from another container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, containers

I created rabbitmq container by running the below command

```
docker run -d --hostname My-rabbit --name test-rabbit -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Created a user called userrabbit and given the permissions as below

```
rabbitmqctl add_user userrabbit password
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags userrabbit administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / userrabbit ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

IP of this(test-rabbit) is 172.17.0.3

I created one more container(172.17.0.4) in which my application is running and in which I need to provide the url of the rabbitmq and I've provided the url as below

```
transport_url = rabbit://userrabbit:password@172.17.0.3:15672/
```

In the logs of container(172.17.0.4), it's showing as

```
AMQP server 172.17.0.3:15672 closed the connection. Check login credentials: Socket closed
```

But I"m able to ping the RabbitMq from the container(172.17.0.4) with the same credentials as shown below

```
curl -i -u userrabbit:password http://172.17.0.3:15672/api/whoami
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
vary: Accept-Encoding, origin
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2017 17:06:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 45
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"name":"userrabbit","tags":"administrator"}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 things...

### first thing:

it's port `5672` for the `transport_url`

the `15672` port you listed is the web admin console

### and second thing:

you need to network you containers together via docker networking.

easiest way is with the `--link` option, provided to the second container at `run` time.

`docker run --link test-rabbit:test-rabbit (... other options here)`

by adding the `--link test-rabbit:test-rabbit` option, your application will be able to see `test-rabbit` as a valid network name with ip address.

### updating your transport url

with these two fixes, your `transport_url` then becomes this

`transport_url = rabbit://userrabbit:password@test-rabbit:5672/`

### other networking options

using `--link` is the easiest way to start, but isn't very scalable.

`docker-compose` makes it really easy to add links between containers

and you can also create custom docker networks via command-line tools and docker-compose, to connect containers together. that's more work, but better long-term.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a hostname for each docker container with `--hostname` option and to add `/etc/host` entries for all the other containers, this you can do with `--add-host` option or by manually editing `/etc/hosts` file.

First create a network so that you can assign IPs: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet1`
Then run the containers:

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.11 --hostname rab1 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --name rab1con -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

and the second one

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.12 --hostname rab2 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --name rab2con -p 15673:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Comment: I tried the following commands it start the containers but they don't join the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Create a docker network so that rabbitmq client can connect to rabbitmq server, both running as docker containers.
Ex

> docker network create sdk-net

Then run the rabbitmq docker using that network and give a name to the same

> docker run -d --rm --name demo-rabbit  --net sdk-net  -p 5672:5672   -p 15672:15672   rabbitmq:3.6.15-management-alpine

Run you client like (note the network name in the run command sdk-net

> docker run --rm  -p 8090:8090 --net sdk-net pythontest

In your client the name of Docker container is reachable. So AMQ connection string will become like

> amqp_url ='amqp://demo-rabbit:5672/'